# Show lineItem error(s) in template?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

If I have a lineItem that needs some validation, for example on an option or note filed, how do I show potential errors in a template and repopulate the form with the posted values?

In addition, I’m working with a template that has multiple products on a page and uses [MulitAdd](https://github.com/engram-design/MultiAdd) to add items to the cart.

I’m validating lineItem data using `onBeforeSaveLineItem` and adding the error with something similar to `$lineItem->addError('text','This is required');`.

Comment: This is a quick guess before testing - but have you tried `$lineItem->addError('options[text]','This is required');`

Comment: You can't attach errors to `$lineItem` because it doesn't exist - you stop it from being created if the validation fails. The above will work if the line item exists in the cart and will show the error message with `{{ item.getError( 'options[text]' ) }}`

Comment: Very good point, yes. I’m not adding the item though if there’s an error. `$event->performAction = false;` gets set instead.

Comment: Trying to find a solution where you attach errors to the cart - would be fine if there was only ever one item on a page, but you state there are multiple? If it were single you could just use `$cart->addError('lineItemOptions[text]','This is required');` Seems messy though.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, multiple items in the add to cart form. I may need to fall back to a general message, which could work but no ideas yet on how to repopulate the form if it fails validation. As you say lineItems don’t exist, and creating a custom model seems messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repopulate the form fields you can use the data from the post request using something like:

`value="{{ craft.request.getPost( 'options.text' ) }}"`

I also think I've got a rough solution for handling the errors.

```
//Add the cart to your event
$cart = craft()->commerce_cart->getCart();

//Check for field/fields
$text = craft()->request->getPost( 'options.text' );

//Check if it's got a value
if ( $text === '' )
{
  $event->performAction = false;

  //Build the handle we'll attach the error to
  //Use the purchasable id (variant) and then add the field we're checking for
  $lineItemErrorHandle = $item->purchasable->id . '-options[text]';

  //Add the error to the cart
  $cart->addError( $lineItemErrorHandle, 'The text is required' );
}
```

Then in your template you display it with the following where `product.defaultVariant.id` needs to be the id of the purchasable that attempted to be added to the cart.

```
{% set string = product.defaultVariant.id ~ '-options[text]' %}
{% if cart.getError( string ) %}
  We've got an error its {{ cart.getError( string ) }}
{% endif %}
```

I had to build the string outside of the `.getError` method because string interpolation wouldn't work using `'#{product.defaultVariant.id}-options[text]'`

Comment: If the form has multiple items there could be multiple options.text fields though, some valid and some not, would this work?

Comment: What does the post request look like for multiple items? The purchasable id makes each error added to the cart unique to the item that through the error. I have only tested this with a single product page though.

Comment: We’re using MultiAdd so the post looks like `items[num][options][text]` –  Perhaps we could loop through `items[]` and match the `purchasable->id`?

Comment: Looking at the MultiAdd docs it looks like you can use `{{ craft.request.getPost( items[{{ loop.index }}][options][text] ) }}` to populate the fields. In the plugin you would then loop through each item in the `items` post array and do the same as if it were a single item.

Comment: Also, having trouble accessing the post data as `'options.text'` actually has a name containing spaces. For example, `option[Item text]`. How do you target that in a template?

Comment: `'options.text'` is the syntax within the plugin. Perhaps take a look at the dev tools to see how the post request is formatted for use inside the template (using `craft.request.getPost()`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41859/discussion-between-luke-pearce-and-james).